# How to change indent guide line color between brackets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change the color of the line between 2 brackets.

I have this:
[image]

Here is what I would like instead:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: dear reader, **1)** if you're interested in colouring _**the brackets themselves**_ (including when bracket pair colourization is enabled) instead of the highlighting of bracket pairs, see [How do I change the colour of brackets in VS Code?](/q/57764284/11107541). **2)** if you're interested in colouring **_matching bracket highlighting**_, see [How can I customize the highlighting of matching bracket/brace/parenthesis pairs in VS Code?](/q/39188214/11107541).

Answer (score 87):

Update for vscode v1.81 (in Insiders now and presumably in Stable early August 2023):

These `colorCustomizations` have been added so that you can separately color the first 6 indent guides - counting from far left in your code to the right, see the demo):

```json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#ffc400",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground2": "#ff0000",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground3": "#a51283",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground4": "#ff8c00",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground5": "#ffc400",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground6": "#ffc400",

           // non-active indent guide colors
    "editorIndentGuide.background1": "#0066ff",
    "editorIndentGuide.background2": "#00e5ff",
    "editorIndentGuide.background3": "#00e5ff",
    "editorIndentGuide.background4": "#00e5ff",
    "editorIndentGuide.background5": "#00e5ff",
    "editorIndentGuide.background6": "#00e5ff"
  }
```

[image: indent guide colors 1-6]

Notice that `editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1` and `editorIndentGuide.background1` refer to the indent guides on the far left and so on.  Only one activeBackground is colored at a time - at whichever level it happens to be from the left.

---

VSCode v.1.23 (released May, 2018) added the ability to colorize the active and other inactive indent guides:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#ff00ff"
}
```

See     [release notes indent guides](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_highlighted-indent-guides)

If you only want the active guides to be visible, set the background of the inactives to transparent ala:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#fff0"
}
```

Comment: You should specify that the settings must be placed inside the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object.

Comment: Why adding another answer instead of editing the first one you posted?
Are they not overlapping?
It puzzles me...

Comment: For anyone looking how to access the ```workbench.colorCustomizations``` settings, go to VSCode -> Preferences -> Settings, type "color customizations" in the search,  and click "Edit in settings.json" when it pops up

Comment: A sincere thank you for this response. Took me longer to read the response than it did to fix the problem. +1 from me.

Answer (score 13):

Those are indent guides.  Their color can be modified in your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

   "editorIndentGuide.background": "#ff0000"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but your solution colorize all indent line. My question is only colorize line between 2 brackets. All others lines stay grey, you know what I mean ?

Answer (score 8):

you can use this,
I believe this is what you want

Reference ： https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_highlighted-indent-guides

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations":{
   "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground":"#ff0000"
}
```

Comment: The  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground" is deprecated. You can use "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Now VS Code 1.66.2(2020) has inbuilt feature for bracket pair colorizer.

1. go to settings of vs code
2. search "bracket pair"

and you will get the settings for bracket pair colorizer.

below video might be of help:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UXlkUo-emY
```

below youtube channel has lots for vs code tips:

```
https://www.youtube.com/c/Code2020/playlists
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an extension for that :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides

Or this one :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SirTori.indenticator

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bracket pair guides colourization, as *white_shadow* suggested, you can change guide colours by these settings:

```
"editor.guides.bracketPairs" : true,
"editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation" : true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal" : "active",

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[YOUR_THEME]": {
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background1": "#FFB86C",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background2": "#FF75B5",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background3": "#45A9F9",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background4": "#B084EB",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background5": "#E6E6E6",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.background6": "#19f9d8",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground1": "#FFB86C",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground2": "#FF75B5",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground3": "#45A9F9",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground4": "#B084EB",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground5": "#E6E6E6",
      "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground6": "#19f9d8",
}
```

You have to change "YOUR_TEME" to your theme name.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color .
Source: https://www.roboleary.net/2021/11/06/vscode-you-dont-need-that-extension2.html

Answer (score 0):

I installed Indent Guides extension from Visual Studio Marketplace.  Worked in VS 2019.