# What is this vertical line in vs code?

Tags: ide, text-editor, visual-studio-code

What is this vertical line? I can't seem to find a name for it. Please refer to image as reference..thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Awesome thank you.

Comment: heres what you needed just a bit more googling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Those are "indent guides", NOT vertical rulers.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942390/how-to-change-indent-guide-line-color-between-brackets-in-vscode for example.  Unfortunately the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: I totally see that now..am new to vs code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to read documentation once got I home. These are indent guides.