# Add white horizontal guide line for block of code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to add horizontal guide line for each block / section of code

I've searched a lot about indentation bot I've get only dots.
This situation might be duplicated but frankly after more than 2 hours on looking on github / stack / google I couldn't solve me this small issue.

Below I've added with red the result that I want to have

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have a look at coloring the indent guides.  For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942390/how-to-change-indent-guide-line-color-between-brackets-in-vscode/50164245?r=SearchResults&s=11|47.4119#50164245 it'll help some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Bracket Pair Colorizer"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) or ["Bracket Pair Colorizer 2"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) by CoenraadS extensions

Comment: This won't help me too much since this extension is looking only on brackets but in my example I don't have only brackets, i have also [], ()

Comment: @durduliu2009 it will colorize () [] and {}. source: am currently using it.

Comment: @durduliu2009 The lines drawn are a bit different of what you show and you can change the colors in a detailed way.

Comment: Yes you are right ... it draws lines between () and []. I have one more question if I may: Is there a posibility to show by default all lines from all codes instead of click on a line and then wait to see the section which is part of

Comment: @durduliu2009 You can look at the source code and determine what is the selection part and disable it. Or add a feature request at the Github site of the extension for an option

Answer (score 0):

This is coming to vscode v1.62, see [Implements horizontal guides for bracket guides.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/134259)
.

For example:

[image: horizontal guides]