# Change background of selected block

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I place my cursor on the extremity of a block (represented by the white drawn cursor on the picture below) VSC highlight both the ending and the starting symbol of that block.

[image]

The red line on the picture represent the starting and the ending of that block. Where can I set the option for VSC to automatically use a background color to highlight the current selected block ? (I am really more of a visual guy and I like to feel where's my current locations when I am coding.)

Comment: Not quite sure how to do what you're asking however Ctrl + ]  switches between matches braces.  Add Shift and it'll select the block which might help in visualisation.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need an extension to do that, it isn't built-in.  Try:

[Indented Block Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=byi8220.indented-block-highlighting)

I am not sure it supports all languages but see if it works in your case.

[Bracket-pair-colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) does something similar but more subtle.  See `"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showHorizontalScopeLine"`.

[image: bracket-pair colorizer scope indicators].

And see [How to change indent guide line color between brackets in VSCODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942390/how-to-change-indent-guide-line-color-between-brackets-in-vscode/50164245#50164245) - perhaps highlighting the active indent guide will be enough for you?

[image: indent guide highlights]

Using (in your settings.json):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorIndentGuide.background": "#bbb",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#f00e0e",\
}
```