# how to change indent-the rainbow extension appearance

Tags: themes, vscode-extensions

I'm using indent-rainbow extension and I want to change the look like here in the picture

[image: like this]

I need to make multi-colored lines

Comment: VS Code can now handle up to 6 indent colors for active and inactive indent guides.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164245/836330.

Answer (score 1):

I find the similar question
https://github.com/oderwat/vscode-indent-rainbow/issues/153

And there is a link for the answer: https://github.com/oderwat/vscode-indent-rainbow#light-mode-new-since-v830

Or text from link:

Light mode (new since v8.3.0)
There is a (new) alternate mode that uses lines (with a customizable width) instead of the background coloring of the whitespace. Here is an example configuration I like:

```
  // Using the light mode
  "indentRainbow.indicatorStyle": "light",
  // we use a simple 1 pixel wide line
  "indentRainbow.lightIndicatorStyleLineWidth": 1,
  // the same colors as above but more visible
  "indentRainbow.colors": [
    "rgba(255,255,64,0.3)",
    "rgba(127,255,127,0.3)",
    "rgba(255,127,255,0.3)",
    "rgba(79,236,236,0.3)"]
```

For this addition, a big thank you goes to Christian Hoock wk1. He also added the editor window reload on config changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to go into the plugin code somewhere. Go to exceptions > rainbow > click on the gear (exception settings) > and in Indent Rainbow: Indicator Style, replace "classic" with "light"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What did I was copy my settings.json elsewhere, categorised them according to extension, or workbench or editor settings etc. Then, one by one, copy them back into my settings.json.
I found my culprit to be:
"editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs".

I removed this, and all was back to normal. :)